# How many kg of seed can one expect from 230 kg of cotton fiber?

Tags: agriculture

So I'm working with data from recent cotton harvest from a seed company. They're more interested in cotton seed than the fiber itself. I'm trying to come up with seed yield numbers for an array of cultivars but the data I was given came in kg of harvested fiber. Excluding any changes between cultivars due to genetics,

Does anyone have an idea of how many kg of cotton seed I can get from a given yield of cotton fiber?

Kind regards,

Comment: That would be a great question for [Agriculture&Farming.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103884/agriculture-farming) (still suggested in Area51 and quite far from having its won site though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this document](https://www.southerncottonginners.org/base/Uploads/Documents/Tom%20Wedegaertner%20-%20Changing%20Dyamics%20for%20Cottonseed%207.21.15.pdf) (pdf) the rate is around 700 lb seed per 500 lb of fibre.

seed = 1·4 × fibre

230 kg fibre ≅ 320 kg seed

(Strangely, the rate has fallen over time.)

Comment: That is strange…

Comment: Curious, it has indeed. 230 kg of fiber in our case yielded 226 kg of seed.